# Airplay and Use of Bluetooth LE accessories

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, airplay

My app is using airplay. Do i need to select "Uses Bluetooth LE accessories" option in info.plist.

I submitted the app with checking this option and my app got rejected. Apple said that "Your app declares support for bluetooth-central in the UIBackgroundModes key in your Info.plist, but does not provide Bluetooth Low Energy functionality. The Bluetooth Background modes are for applications that communicate to other devices using Bluetooth Low Energy and the Core Bluetooth framework."

[image]

Comment: No, Airplay connects via WiFi, not BLE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just check the airplay not the other options . Like in picture you should only select first one unless you are also using LE and implementing corebluetooth.
[image]